# Simulate tap in wpf using windows 7 touch framework

Tags: wpf

How does button works in regards to tapping?

I would like to simulate a tapping on a control. To do so I cannot just handle 'TouchUp' event because I want to ensure the user tapped on that location and didn't just move his finger and released it over my control.

Good scenario: Tapping on my control

Bad scenario: touching on a place outside my control, Moving while touching to my control, Releasing the touch -> This will cause to touch up yet I don't want to handle that scenario.

Eran.

Comment: I'm confused, do you want to simulate a button press, or are you trying to cope with users moving their fingers onto your control?

Comment: @Surfbutler - I'm trying to simulate a button press without using button element.

Comment: Ok, the confusion is with the word 'simulate'. To me that implied programmatically aending a touch message to your program without the user doing anything. I'm surprised your control is getting a touchup event if the user didn't touch down on it. Are you actually seeing this behaviour, or are you just of thinking of scenarios in which there could be problems?

Comment: Did you actually get a TouchUp after moving a finger onto your control, or do you just assume that it behaves like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for replying. I found the answer.

If you explicitly force capture to specific element (ie elementA) then all the following events will be routed to that element.

```
 private void elementA_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
 {
    elementA.CaptureTouch(e.TouchDevice);
 }
```

If you don't force capture to a specific element then the touch up event will fire on the last element you were on his boundaries when you release the touch.